# Batch Processing Files In RX7 from Reaper

Tags: reaper, audio-restoration, izotope, batch-processing

Put simply: I'm looking for a way to select multiple items(audio clips) in Reaper and open them all in Izotope RX's Batch processing window.

It is easy enough to open (up to 16) items in the normal RX editing window using the "open items in editor" command to process them all one by one. But this doesn't allow for a quick way of getting files direct from reaper into the batch processing window of RX.

Open to all suggestions: Scripting, external editors, crazy workarounds.